# When is it necessary set up S2S Security Token service for an App

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-addin, s2s

I have built both SharePoint hosted and provided hosted apps. One thing I think that is not obvious is when you are required to set up the S2S Security token issuer service (STS) to provide access tokens for authentication.

Am I correct in thinking that this is only really required for on prem provider hosted apps and even with those, when you are using managed code e.g `Token.cs`?

Therefore you can happily create an Developer Site or even a App catalogue for SharePoint hosted apps and be blissfully unaware of the above prereq?

Answer (score 0):

> SharePoint 2013 on-premises can use either the low-trust or high-trust
>   model.  Office 365 does not provide the ability to register high-trust
>   apps, which makes sense because registering the public-key portion of
>   the certificate requires farm administrator privileges (you do not
>   have farm administrator privileges in O365).
>
> Side note: It now makes perfect sense that apps obtained from the
>   SharePoint Store can only be used when the app uses an Azure ACS
>   trust.  The store trusts ACS, SharePoint trusts ACS, and your app
>   trusts ACS.  This is how end users can obtain and install apps in a
>   SharePoint farm without requiring a farm administrator.

In SharePoint hosted there is no need for authentication tokens as the app runs within SharePoint.
See this for more information:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2014/07/14/high-trust-sharepoint-apps-on-non-microsoft-platforms.aspx

Comment: thanks for your answer and your useful link. However, in my question I guess I was referring to a "no need to trust" model and hence when is it appropriate to set up S2S.

Comment: A trust needs to be established between SharePoint and the app. S2S can be used only in case of on-perm apps. And is appropriate if you don't want to go for Azure.

Comment: Yes thanks I think you mean on prem provider hosted Apps which effectively means the run on  IIS .